# Find current users active directory group C++

Tags: c++, ldap, activedirectorymembership

How would I go about querying what active directory group the currently logged in user belongs to? I am assuming it will be through LDAP but I havnt been able to find much on how to get this particular information.

I have put together some code but im not quite sure what I need to do next

```
    // Open the access token associated with the calling process.
if (OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(),
                     TOKEN_QUERY,
                     &hToken) == FALSE)
{
    dwErrorCode = GetLastError();
    wprintf(L"OpenProcessToken failed. GetLastError returned: %d\n", dwErrorCode);
    return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(dwErrorCode);
}

// Retrieve the token information in a TOKEN_USER structure.
GetTokenInformation(hToken,
                    TokenUser,      // Request for a TOKEN_USER structure.
                    NULL,
                    0,
                    &dwBufferSize);

pTokenUser = (PTOKEN_USER) new BYTE[dwBufferSize];
memset(pTokenUser, 0, dwBufferSize);
if (GetTokenInformation(hToken,
                        TokenUser,
                        pTokenUser,
                        dwBufferSize,
                        &dwBufferSize))
{
    CloseHandle(hToken);
}
else
{
    dwErrorCode = GetLastError();
    wprintf(L"GetTokenInformation failed. GetLastError returned: %d\n", dwErrorCode);
    return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(dwErrorCode);
}

if (IsValidSid(pTokenUser->User.Sid) == FALSE)
{
    wprintf(L"The owner SID is invalid.\n");
    delete [] pTokenUser;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your particular case I think you can do without any LDAP calls. Here's a suggestion:

- use `GetCurrentProcessId` and `OpenProcess` to get a handle to the current process
- call `OpenProcessToken` on that handle to open the access token associated with the current process
- call `GetTokenInformation` on that access token, with a token information class of `TokenGroups`
- the resulting `TOKEN_GROUPS` structure contains a list with the SIDs and attributes of all the groups in the access token
- call `LookupAccountSid` on the SID of each group in the list to obtain its name

MSDN should provide more detailed information about the calls mentioned above.

Comment: I started to put together some code but im not sure what I need to do in the last step using LookupAccountSid

Comment: Assume the call to `GetTokenInformation` was successful; you should now have a pointer to a `TOKEN_GROUPS` structure, `ptokengroups`. For each of the `ptokengroups->GroupCount` groups, call `LookupAccountSid` on `ptokengroups->Groups[idx].Sid`.

Comment: I see you've edited the question and added code that uses `GetTokenInformation` with `TokenUser` instead of `TokenGroups`, although you originally said you wanted to retrieve the groups the current user is a member of. Anyway, given the code, you could now  retrieve the name and domain of the user by calling `LookupAccountSid`, the first time with NULL output buffers to retrieve their sizes, and then with valid ones: `LookupAccountSid(NULL, (pTokenUser->User).Sid, name, &namesize, domainname, &domainnamesize, &use)`, with `SID_NAME_USE use = SidTypeUnknown`. Proceed similarly for the groups.