# Checking (in C++) if the user is a member of a certain LDAP/AD group

Tags: c++, active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

I'm maintaining a C++ application. We have to add a call to LDAP/AD for authorization. But I'm not expert on LDAP/AD (or COM calls), and there seems to be a lot of different ways to access LDAP/AD. I would be very grateful for some advice!

What I want to do is to "check if the current user is a member of a certain Active Directory group". (The user will then get special privileges in our application.) We have the group name - and we have a "fully distinguished name", looking like this: `"CN=TheGroupName,OU=Groups,OU=_GlobalResources,OU=OrgCode,DC=domainpart1,DC=domainpart2,DC=net"`

My plan was to do like this: [Find current users active directory group C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505336/find-current-users-active-directory-group-c) Read user information with GetCurrentProcessId + OpenProcess + OpenProcessToken + GetTokenInformation (with TokenGroups), iterate through the groups and do a LookupAccountSid for each group SID until I found the group. But the LookupAccountSid call was slow - it took way too long.

There was an easy solution in C#: [Check whether current user is a member of an active directory group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152667/check-whether-current-user-is-a-member-of-an-active-directory-group) But how do I do this efficiently in C++?

Should I ...

(a) ... perform a direct query to the LDAP? Is there a way to make a "is the current user a member of this group?"-call? (Using the distinguished name in the call.)

-or-

(b) ... convert the distinguished name to a SID, get user information with GetTokenInformation/TokenGroups, and then see if the SID for the group matches any of the SIDs in the returned member-of-groups-array? Getting the SID array for the user's groups is easy, but how do I (quickly) convert the distinguished name for the group to a SID?

-or-

(c) ... use some completely different approach? :-)

Comment: The best approach I believe is to convert TheGroupName dn to sid via ldap query, then try to find this sid in user token groups. Token groups should contain nested groups sid's as well. However, if TheGroupName is a domain local group in domain A and user belongs to domain B, the group sid may not be listed in user's token groups. Please check this case if needed

Comment: To query sid property of the group you can use ADSI. This article contains C++ example of how to bind to an object and extract its properties https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms806997.aspx#buildingadapps_using_good_adsi

Comment: Thanks for your help, Dmitry! :-) I found a solution digging in the Microsoft documentation you linked to. You didn't post your comments as an answer, so I couldn't "accept" it, but I upvoted both your comments.